# Qt: How to synchronize access to data from multiple threads in model/view setup?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

How to synchronize access to data accessed from multiple threads in Qt model/view setup?

I'm using `QTableView` with a `Model` class.

`Model` extends `QAbstractTableModel` and has an instance of a custom class `Net` that holds actual data to be displayed to `QTableView` through `data()` call (accessed by `Model::data()`)

My class listens on network data and runs on separate thread from which it updates it's data (simple fixed size array of 10 strings).

Data in my class has to be accessed both by a thread that constantly updates it and from Qt GUI by calling `data()` on `Model`.

I would assume I need to use mutex to synchronize access to my array of strings but `QAbstractTableModel::data()` is a `const` method so I can't lock `boost::mutex` in it.

What is a general pattern for synchronizing access to data in class that extends `QAbstractTableModel` and provides data to `QTableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Qt's item-view classes (like QAbstractTableModel) and multiple threads will go together very well.  The problem is that the QAbstractTableModel class is expected to notify all of the associated view classes every time the data changes, and also the view classes expect to be able to read data from the data-model at any time.  Implementing that would be difficult to do (efficiently, anyway) if the updates and data are owned by a different thread.  I suspect any multithreaded solution you came up with would need to be serialized so heavily that only one of the two threads would end up running at a time anyway, at which point you've effectively gone back to a single-threaded program, just with a very convoluted design :)

My suggestion would be to move your 10-string database into the main/Qt thread instead, if possible.  Your networking operations can be moved into the main thread as well (use QSocketNotifier objects and make sure the I/O is all non-blocking, so that it can't hold off the Qt event loop and damage GUI performance); or you could keep the networking in a separate network thread and just have the network-thread send update-messages to the main/Qt thread telling the main/Qt thread how to update the database/table-model.  The key is to have all reads and writes to the data model's database done by the main/Qt thread.

Comment: The first time I tried to use Qt's model/views was in a multithreaded codebase, and thought "ummm...yeah, this does not seem to work."  http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2009-August/011043.html

Comment: The `Net` class holds my business logic and uses third party library for networking so I prefer to separate it from Qt model (Qt model/view design document suggests similar approach). Data are not owned by a different thread but are accessed in callback from separate thread. I'm locking the data just to read/write couple of string values, it seems to work so far. I'm typecasting the const away from mutex in the `Model::data()` handler to be able to read data. There seems to be lot of stuff in `Qt` that works in cute little examples but needs lots of hooking up for real world code.

Comment: @HostileFork I've looked at your linked discussion - this week I've built simple model/view Qt app (I don't usually do gui apps, I'm more network guy, prefer Cocoa/Mac then Qt/Linux) that shows 2 tables each 3x10 of data (double values formatted as strings). The model has internal class that uses another 3rd party networked library with it's own queue (I assume running it's own thread) to get the data off network. During the day I'm somewhere near 4000 full table updates per minute x2 (same data from 2 sources), each message updates all items in table ... works for me so far.